# Problems with ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

in the work I have a task to install Zabbix Agent on a list of machines using Ansible.
My problem is that the machines have some cache problems and I tried to solve it using Ansible but with no succed, I've tried using

`- command: apt-get install -f
     become: true`

and also

`- name: Update and upgrade apt packages
  become: true
  apt:
    upgrade: yes
    update_cache: yes`

But always I have an pretty big error message.

> fatal: [MACHINE IP]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["apt-get", "install", "-f"], "delta": "0:01:13.499864", "end": "2018-11-21 17:55:11.172264", "msg": "non-zero return code", 
>   "rc": 100, "start": "2018-11-21 17:53:57.672400", "stderr": "No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.\nNo apport report 
>   written because MaxReports is reached already\nNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already\nNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already\nNo apport 
>   report written because MaxReports is reached already\nNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already\nNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already\nNo 
>   apport report written because MaxReports is reached already\nNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already\nNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already\nNo 
>   apport report written because MaxReports is reached already\nNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already\nNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already\nE:
>    Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)", "stderr_lines": ["No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.", 
>    "No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already", "No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already", "No apport report written because MaxReports is reached 
>    already", "No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already", "No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already", "No apport report written because MaxReports 
>    is reached already", "No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already", "No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already", "No apport report written because 
>    MaxReports is reached already", "No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already", "No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already", "No apport report written 
>    because MaxReports is reached already", "E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"], "stdout": "Reading package lists...\nBuilding dependency tree...\nReading state 
>    information...\nThe following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:\n  libcurl3 linux-headers-4.4.0-101 linux-headers-4.4.0-101-generic\n
>    linux-headers-4.4.0-103 linux-headers-4.4.0-103-generic\n  linux-headers-4.4.0-104 linux-headers-4.4.0-104-generic\n  linux-headers-4.4.0-109 linux-headers-4.4.0-109-generic\n
>    linux-headers-4.4.0-112 linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic\n  linux-headers-4.4.0-116 linux-headers-4.4.0-116-generic\n  linux-headers-4.4.0-31 linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic 
>    linux-headers-4.4.0-87\n  linux-headers-4.4.0-87-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-96\n  linux-headers-4.4.0-96-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-97\n  linux-headers-4.4.0-97-generic 
>    linux-headers-4.4.0-98\n  linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic\n  linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic\n
>    linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic\n  linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic\n  linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic 
>    linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic\n  linux-image-4.4.0-97-generic linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic\n  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic\n
>    linux-image-extra-4.4.0-104-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic\n  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic\n
>    linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic\n  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-97-generic\n
>    linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic\nUse 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.\n0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 143 not upgraded.\n15 not fully installed or removed.\nAfter 
>    this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.\nSetting up initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.1) ...\r\nupdate-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)\r\nSetting up 
>    linux-firmware (1.157.20) ...\r\nupdate-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-108-generic\r\nW: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.\r\n\r\ngzip: stdout: No space left on 
>    device\r\nE: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1\r\nupdate-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-108-generic with 1.\r\ndpkg: error processing package linux-firmware 
>    (--configure):\r\n subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1\r\nSetting up linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic (4.4.0-139.165) 
>    ...\r\nRunning depmod.\r\nupdate-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)\r\nThe link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-138-generic\r\nExamining 
>    /etc/kernel/postinst.d.\r\nrun-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-139-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-139-generic\r\nrun-parts: 
>    executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-139-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-139-generic\r\nupdate-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-139-generic\r\nW: mdadm: 
>    /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.\r\n\r\ngzip: stdout: No space left on device\r\nE: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1\r\nupdate-initramfs: failed for 
>    /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-139-generic with 1.\r\nrun-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1\r\nFailed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at 
>    /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic.postinst line 1052.\r\ndpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic (--configure):\r\n subprocess installed post-installation 
>    script returned error exit status 2\r\ndpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-139-generic:\r\n linux-image-extra-4.4.0-139-generic 
>    depends on linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic; however:\r\n  Package linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic is not configured yet.\r\n\r\ndpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-139-generic
>    (--configure):\r\n dependency problems - leaving unconfigured\r\ndpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:\r\n linux-image-generic 
>    depends on linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic; however:\r\n  Package linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic is not configured yet.\r\n linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-139-generic;
>    however:\r\n  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-139-generic is not configured yet.\r\n linux-image-generic depends on linux-firmware; however:\r\n  Package linux-firmware is not 
>    configured yet.\r\n\r\ndpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):\r\n dependency problems - leaving unconfigured\r\ndpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of
>    linux-generic:\r\n linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 4.4.0.139.145); however:\r\n  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.\r\n\r\ndpkg: error processing package 
>    linux-generic (--configure):\r\n dependency problems - leaving unconfigured\r\nSetting up linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic (4.4.0-109.132) ...\r\nInternal Error: Could not find image 
>    (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-109-generic)\r\ndpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic (--configure):\r\n subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
>    status 2\r\nSetting up linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic (4.4.0-112.135) ...\r\nInternal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic)\r\ndpkg: error processing package 
>    linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic (--configure):\r\n subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2\r\nSetting up linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic (4.4.0-116.140)
>    ...\r\nRunning depmod.\r\nupdate-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)\r\nThe link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-139-generic\r\nExamining 
>    /etc/kernel/postinst.d.\r\nrun-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-116-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-116-generic\r\nrun-parts: executing 
>    /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-116-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-116-generic\r\nupdate-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-116-generic\r\nW: mdadm: 
>    /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.\r\n\r\ngzip: stdout: No space left on device\r\nE: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1\r\nupdate-initramfs: failed for 
>    /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-116-generic with 1.\r\nrun-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1\r\nFailed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at 
>    /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic.postinst line 1052.\r\ndpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic (--configure):\r\n subprocess installed 
>    post-installation script returned error exit status 2\r\nSetting up linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic (4.4.0-138.164) ...\r\nRunning depmod.\r\nupdate-initramfs: deferring update 
>    (hook will be called later)\r\nThe link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-116-generic\r\nExamining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.\r\nrun-parts: 
>    executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-138-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-138-generic\r\nrun-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-138-generic 
>    /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-138-generic\r\nupdate-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-138-generic\r\nW: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.\r\n\r\ngzip: stdout: 
>    No space left on device\r\nE: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1\r\nupdate-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-138-generic with 1.\r\nrun-parts: 
>    /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1\r\nFailed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic.postinst line 
>    1052.\r\ndpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic (--configure):\r\n subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2\r\nSetting up
>    linux-image-extra-4.4.0-108-generic (4.4.0-108.131) ...\r\ndepmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-108-generic: No such file or directory\r\nrun-parts: executing 
>    /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-108-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-108-generic\r\nrun-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-108-generic
>    /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-108-generic\r\nupdate-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-108-generic\r\nW: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.\r\n\r\ngzip: 
>    stdout: No space left on device\r\nE: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1\r\nupdate-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-108-generic with 1.\r\nrun-parts: 
>    /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1\r\ndpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-108-generic (--configure):\r\n subprocess
>    installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1\r\ndpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic:\r\n 
>    linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic; however:\r\n  Package linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic is not configured yet.\r\n\r\ndpkg: 
>   error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic (--configure):\r\n dependency problems - leaving unconfigured\r\ndpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of 
>   linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic:\r\n linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic; however:\r\n  Package linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic is
>   not configured yet.\r\n\r\ndpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic (--configure):\r\n dependency problems - leaving unconfigured\r\ndpkg: dependency 
>   problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic:\r\n linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic; however:\r\n
>   Package linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic is not configured yet.\r\n\r\ndpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic (--configure):\r\n dependency problems - 
>   leaving unconfigured\r\ndpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic:\r\n linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic depends on 
>   linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic; however:\r\n  Package linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic is not configured yet.\r\n\r\ndpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic
>   (--configure):\r\n dependency problems - leaving unconfigured\r\nProcessing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.1) ...\r\nupdate-initramfs: Generating 
>   /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-108-generic\r\nW: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.\r\n\r\ngzip: stdout: No space left on device\r\nE: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 
>   1\r\nupdate-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-108-generic with 1.\r\ndpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):\r\n subprocess installed post-installation 
>   script returned error exit status 1\r\nErrors were encountered while processing:\r\n linux-firmware\r\n linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic\r\n linux-image-extra-4.4.0-139-generic\r\n 
>   linux-image-generic\r\n linux-generic\r\n linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic\r\n linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic\r\n linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic\r\n linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic\r\n 
>   linux-image-extra-4.4.0-108-generic\r\n linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic\r\n linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic\r\n linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic\r\n 
>   linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic\r\n initramfs-tools", "stdout_lines": ["Reading package lists...", "Building dependency tree...", "Reading state information...", 
>   "The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:", "  libcurl3 linux-headers-4.4.0-101 linux-headers-4.4.0-101-generic", "  linux-headers-4.4.0-103 
>   linux-headers-4.4.0-103-generic", "  linux-headers-4.4.0-104 linux-headers-4.4.0-104-generic", "  linux-headers-4.4.0-109 linux-headers-4.4.0-109-generic", "
>   linux-headers-4.4.0-112 linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic", "  linux-headers-4.4.0-116 linux-headers-4.4.0-116-generic", "  linux-headers-4.4.0-31 linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic 
>   linux-headers-4.4.0-87", "  linux-headers-4.4.0-87-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-96", "  linux-headers-4.4.0-96-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-97", "  linux-headers-4.4.0-97-generic 
>   linux-headers-4.4.0-98", "  linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic", "  linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic", "
>   linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic", "  linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic", "  linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic", "
>   linux-image-4.4.0-97-generic linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic", "  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic", "  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-104-generic 
>   linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic", "  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic", "  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic", "
>   linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-97-generic", "  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic", "Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.", "0 upgraded, 0 newly 
>   installed, 0 to remove and 143 not upgraded.", "15 not fully installed or removed.", "After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.", "Setting up initramfs-tools 
>   (0.122ubuntu8.1) ...", "update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)", "Setting up linux-firmware (1.157.20) ...", "update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-108-generic",
>   "W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.", "", "gzip: stdout: No space left on device", "E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1", "update-initramfs: failed for 
>   /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-108-generic with 1.", "dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):", " subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1", 
>   "Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic (4.4.0-139.165) ...", "Running depmod.", "update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)", "The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto 
>   /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-138-generic", "Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.", "run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-139-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-139-generic", 
>   "run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-139-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-139-generic", "update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-139-generic", "W: mdadm:
>    /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.", "", "gzip: stdout: No space left on device", "E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1", "update-initramfs: failed for 
>    /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-139-generic with 1.", "run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1", "Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at 
>    /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic.postinst line 1052.", "dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic (--configure):", " 
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2", "dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-139-generic:", 
>    " linux-image-extra-4.4.0-139-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic; however:", "  Package linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic is not configured yet.", "", 
>    "dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-139-generic (--configure):", " dependency problems - leaving unconfigured", "dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of 
>    linux-image-generic:", " linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic; however:", "  Package linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic is not configured yet.", " linux-image-generic 
>    depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-139-generic; however:", "  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-139-generic is not configured yet.", " linux-image-generic depends on linux-firmware; 
>    however:", "  Package linux-firmware is not configured yet.", "", "dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):", " dependency problems - leaving unconfigured", 
>    "dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:", " linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 4.4.0.139.145); however:", "  Package linux-image-generic is not 
>    configured yet.", "", "dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):", " dependency problems - leaving unconfigured", "Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic 
>    (4.4.0-109.132) ...", "Internal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-109-generic)", "dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic (--configure):", " 
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2", "Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic (4.4.0-112.135) ...", "Internal Error: Could not find image 
>    (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic)", "dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic (--configure):", " subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
>    status 2", "Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic (4.4.0-116.140) ...", "Running depmod.", "update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)", "The link /initrd.img is
>     a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-139-generic", "Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.", "run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-116-generic 
>     /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-116-generic", "run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-116-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-116-generic", "update-initramfs: Generating 
>     /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-116-generic", "W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.", "", "gzip: stdout: No space left on device", "E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1", 
>     "update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-116-generic with 1.", "run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1", "Failed to process 
>     /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic.postinst line 1052.", "dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic (--configure):", 
>     " subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2", "Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic (4.4.0-138.164) ...", "Running depmod.", 
>     "update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)", "The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-116-generic", "Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.", 
>     "run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-138-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-138-generic", "run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 
>     4.4.0-138-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-138-generic", "update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-138-generic", "W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.", "", 
>     "gzip: stdout: No space left on device", "E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1", "update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-138-generic with 1.", 
>     "run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1", "Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic.postinst line 
>     1052.", "dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic (--configure):", " subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2", 
>     "Setting up linux-image-extra-4.4.0-108-generic (4.4.0-108.131) ...", "depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-108-generic: No such file or directory", 
>     "run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-108-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-108-generic", "run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 
>     4.4.0-108-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-108-generic", "update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-108-generic", "W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.", "", 
>     "gzip: stdout: No space left on device", "E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1", "update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-108-generic with 1.", 
>     "run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1", "dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-108-generic (--configure):", 
>     " subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1", "dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic:", 
>     " linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic; however:", "  Package linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic is not configured yet.", "", 
>     "dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic (--configure):", " dependency problems - leaving unconfigured", "dpkg: dependency problems 
>     prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic:", " linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic; however:", "  Package 
>     linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic is not configured yet.", "", "dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic (--configure):", " dependency problems
>      - leaving unconfigured", "dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic:", " linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic depends on 
>      linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic; however:", "  Package linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic is not configured yet.", "", "dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic 
>      (--configure):", " dependency problems - leaving unconfigured", "dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic:", " 
>   linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic; however:", "  Package linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic is not configured yet.", "", 
>   "dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic (--configure):", " dependency problems - leaving unconfigured", "Processing triggers for initramfs-tools 
>   (0.122ubuntu8.1) ...", "update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-108-generic", "W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.", "", "gzip: stdout: No space left on device", 
>   "E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1", "update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-108-generic with 1.", "dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):", 
>   " subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1", "Errors were encountered while processing:", " linux-firmware", " linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic", 
>   " linux-image-extra-4.4.0-139-generic", " linux-image-generic", " linux-generic", " linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic", " linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic", " linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic", 
>   " linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic", " linux-image-extra-4.4.0-108-generic", " linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic", " linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic", 
>   " linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic", " linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic", " initramfs-tools"]}

When I try to install it without Ansible everything works fine until I tried to start the service

> -- Unit zabbix-agent.service has begun starting up.
>   Nov 22 16:03:00 FRPARUDASTOH02 zabbix_agentd[2748]: zabbix_agentd [2748]: /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf.d: [2] No such file or directory
>   Nov 22 16:03:00 FRPARUDASTOH02 systemd[1]: zabbix-agent.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
>   Nov 22 16:03:00 FRPARUDASTOH02 systemd[1]: Failed to start Zabbix Agent.
>   -- Subject: Unit zabbix-agent.service has failed
>   -- Defined-By: systemd

The Linux that I'm sing are Ubuntu 16

Comment: What specific errors did you encounter when trying to install it without Ansible?  What specific errors did you encounter when trying to install it with Ansible?  Your question needs more details on the errors.  Please check out the FAQ on how to ask good questions.

Comment: `some cache problems` what cache problems? `pretty big error message.`  what error message?

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow. Here is some info on asking a good question [ask]. Also as indentation is important in yaml and Ansible formatting your code correctly would be useful in addition to adding the error you received.

Comment: Read the error message and act occordingly. `zabbix` packages are sometimes unmaintained cause they change sometimes often, create the `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf.d` directory or remove the include statemtnt from `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agent(d?).conf` configuration file. Do you run your ansible with root permissions on the other machine? If not, you might get No space left on device errors, maybe. And you better cleanup those unnedded kernel packages - they just use up space.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of `stdout: No space left on device` messages in that log. 
Your `/var` may be full and causing numerous issues.